# Xamarin Android TV app crashes in debugger

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, visual-studio-2019

Today I upgraded to VS2019 and removed 2017 and I deleted and re-created my Android TV VM.

Now when I run the project the interface shows up but touching any button will make the app crash with the following logs:

https://pastebin.com/tuCJeHzA

I am not even sure what exactly is crashing the app, but am expecting this part:

`04-03 03:58:18.278 androidtv   Error   2621    PrtnrWidgetInfoLdr  java.lang.SecurityException: Failed to find provider tvlauncher.widget for user 0; expected to find a valid ContentProvider for this authority`

When running the project in VS2017 it works fine again.

What could be the issue here?

Comment: Are you testing a newer TV emulator API level than you previously used? "Assuming" you have not implemented a `ContentProvider` subclass in your app? If you have, post the subclass and the manifest additions for exposing the provider to the OS.

Comment: I tried upgrading to API 27 but nothing worked. I downgraded to API25 with a fresh emulator but now it's just giving me a back screen without it actually running the app. I'm going to install VS2017 again and see if that solves it.